# Invoke function from jquery plugin boiler plate code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, boilerplate

I have found nice jQuery plugin and it uses boiler plate template. Everything works fine, but I can't invoke internal function to get selected items.
The construction of this plugin is below:

```
    (function ($, window, document) {
    'use strict';

    // constructor
    var SearchableOptionList = function ($element, options) {
        this.$originalElement = $element;
        this.options = options;

        this.metadata = this.$originalElement.data('sol-options');
    };

    // plugin prototype
    SearchableOptionList.prototype = {

        DATA_KEY: 'sol-element',

        // default option values
        defaults: {            
            ... 
        },

        // initialize the plugin
        init: function () {
            this.config = $.extend(true, {}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata);

            ...

            return this;
        },

        //some functions
        ...

        selectAll: function () {
            ...
        },

        deselectAll: function () {
            ...
        },

        getSelection: function () {
            return this.$selection.find('input:checked');
        }
    };

    // jquery plugin boiler plate code
    SearchableOptionList.defaults = SearchableOptionList.prototype.defaults;
    window.SearchableOptionList = SearchableOptionList;

    $.fn.searchableOptionList = function (options) {
        var result = [];
        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $alreadyInitializedSol = $this.data(SearchableOptionList.prototype.DATA_KEY);

            if ($alreadyInitializedSol) {
                result.push($alreadyInitializedSol);
            } else {
                var newSol = new SearchableOptionList($this, options);
                result.push(newSol);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    newSol.init();
                }, 0);
            }
        });

        if (result.length === 1) {
            return result[0];
        }

        return result;
    };

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Full code you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/pbauerochse/searchable-option-list).

I try to invoke `getSelection` function like below:

```
// initialize sol
    var s = $('#my-select').searchableOptionList({
        maxHeight: '150px',
        showSelectAll: true
    });

    s.selectAll();
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: this.config is undefined
```

Is it possible to invoke functions using this template of boiler plate?

You can play around on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/651vqp9n/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [line 1031](https://github.com/pbauerochse/searchable-option-list/blob/master/sol.js#L1031) is the culprit

```
        setTimeout(function() {
            newSol.init();
        }, 0);
```

Since the init is deferred the code is not ready when you call it right away. The esiest fix is to defer your call too, but there is no gurantee that it will be initialized.

```
setTimeout(function(){s.selectAll()},1000);
```

The better solution is to use the plugin's [events](http://pbauerochse.github.io/searchable-option-list/configuration.html#events) to hook into when it has been initialized.

```
$('#my-select').searchableOptionList({
  maxHeight: '150px',
  events: {
    onInitialized: function() {
      this.selectAll();
    }
  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km700q4u/)

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why author use `setTimeout`? Is it necessary?

Comment: I'm guessing it is because the plugin allows for remote data so it treats all data asynchronously.

Comment: If I am not going to use async data can I omit this?

Comment: You could, but it does not hurt any to leave it in. Note that there is one other place that the timeout would have to be removed `setTimeout(function () { sol._initializeData();` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td919pvv/)

Comment: Excelent! Now it works as I expect. Thanks a lot for help! For those who don't want to store instance of plugin can use `$('#my-select').searchableOptionList().selectAll();`